# Альтернативный текст внутри input'а

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Представим, есть на сайте форма авторизации, input'ы для логина/пароля. Сверху написано - куда чего вводить. Как сделать, что бы у input'ов значение что за поле было уже внутри, а при установке туда курсора - исчезало и если input'ы не заполнены, и нажали кнопку отправить, то значения которые передаются были пустыми?

P.S. Это не value.

Comment: (шепотом) это placeholder. гугле ит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот тут  посмотрите: [подсказка для поля формы](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=1&id=425).

Comment: т.к. кроссбраузерно, принимаю этот ответ.

Answer (score 5):

Есть атрибут в html `placeholder`. Попробуйте его использовать.
**Минусы:** Его не подерживает ИЕ и старые браузеры ( Mozila<4.0, Opera<11.0, Safari<5.0)

Answer (score 2):

```
<input id="1" value="text" onmouseover="document.getElementById('1').value = ' ';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('1').value = 'text';">
```

Comment: тоже вариант. да еще и по коду меньше!

Answer (score 0):

Никаких onmouseover и onmouseout

```
<input id="1" value="text" onfocus="if (this.value == 'подсказка') this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == "") this.value = 'подсказка';" />
```

Comment: Не будет работать, т.к. надо иметь стандартное значение, т.е value, но в этом случае при отправке поля будут не пустые. (Условие вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        var objSearch = document.getElementById('front_search_query');
        objSearch.onfocus = function()  { if(objSearch.value=='Поиск') objSearch.value = '';}
        objSearch.onblur = function()   { if(objSearch.value=='') objSearch.value = 'Поиск';}
        </script>
```